# Conditional entropy for Conditional random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, information-theory

If $X,Y,Z$ are three different random variables, and let H($\cdot$) determine entropy, is it true that

$H(X|Y,Z) = H(X|Z \ | \ Y|Z) = H(X|Y \ | \ Z|Y)$ ?

If it is not true in general, then can one say anything particular when $X,Y,Z$ are Gaussians, and jointly Gaussian.

Comment: Can you define the second entropy and the third one?

Comment: They are defined in the same way how you would define standard conditional entropy. For instance let $U = X|Z$ and $V=Y|Z$, then $H(X|Z \ | \ Y|Z) = H(U | V)$.

Comment: I guess my question is can I manipulate the term $H(X|Y,Z)$ in the manner I suggested originally ? It seems like it could be true. For instance if $X,Y,Z$ are jointly Gaussian, then X|Y,Z is the same as $X|Y \ | \ Z|Y$, and $X|Z \ | \ Y|Z$.

Comment: Is the distribution of $X|Z$ a function of $Z=z$? Then $H(X|Z\ |\ Y|Z)$ is itself a function of $Z$, hence random. You could evaluate $H(X|Z\ |\ Y|Z, Z)$, though.